# Redis HA using Docker & Kubernetes (1 Master 2 slaves) Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: redis, ubuntu-16.04, high-availability, redis-sentinel

I'm trying to find a viable solution using Redis as a Master/Slave(at least 2 slaves) configuration.  I have Docker containers with Ubuntu 16.04 OS & Redis server/sentinel installed (latest stable).

I'm not looking for a clustered setup.  I would like to have the master redis db on one pod, and the slaves on their own pod (all three will be on separate vm's or physical boxes).  I'll want to use yaml/Kubernetes nodeSelector to assign where they can spin up.

From my research, it appears I want to run Redis Sentinel services on each pod as well.  They key here as well is I want to specify where each Master/Slave POD can run.  I've investigated https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/redis  but that does not give me the control I want.  Maybe Redis 4.x helps, but I can't find any examples.  Any pointers would be appreciated.  I've searched all over this site for an answer w/o any luck.

Comment: To answer my own question, this was the best resource.  https://github.com/oberthur/docker-redis

Comment: Link doesn't work!